# How to read data from file as String or Bytes from in swift 5 using readData function

Tags: file, read-data, swift5

i am trying to read content of the file using **readData** function .I am able to read data from the file currently it is displaying size of content read from file but i want actual content of the file .

Code using for reading file

```
var fileHandle = FileHandle(forReadingAtPath: FullFileName as String)
var data = fileHandle?.readData(ofLength: 10)
var availabledata = fileHandle!.availableData
print("data")
print(data)
print("availabledata")
print(availabledata)
```

Output

```
data
Optional(10 bytes)
availabledata
11 bytes
```

Q1. How can i print actual content read from the file ? 
please suggest method related to the readData function only .

Answer (score 0):

> How can i print actual content read from the file ? please suggest method related to the readData function only .

The question isn't really tied to `readData` – this function returns `Data?`, an optional value. When you print this you will get `Option(x bytes)` where the `x bytes` is the `.description` of the value.

If you wish to print the byte values you need to write something to produce your desired format. For example:

```
print(data?.map { $0 })
```

will print the data as an array of `UInt8`. If you wish to format each byte differently, say as hex, change the closure to produce the format you wish – each byte gets passed to the closure as a `UInt8` value.

This is far from the only way to do it, you just need to wrote what you need as `Data` itself doesn't provide a `description` that meets your needs.

HTH